two definitions of degree of invertible sheaf on projective curve
Hi I saw two defs from Vakil's FOAG and Görtz&Wedhorn’s AG for the degree of invertible sheaves on projective curve:

(Vakil's) 18.4.2. Important definition: degree of a line bundle on a projective curve (generalized in §18.4.7). Suppose $\mathscr{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on a projective curve C over k. (We make no assumption on the regularity, or even reducedness, of C!) Define the degree of $\mathscr{L}$ (denoted $\operatorname{deg} \mathscr{L}$ or $\operatorname{deg}_{\mathrm{C}} \mathscr{L}$ ) by
$$
\operatorname{deg} \mathscr{L}:=\chi(\mathrm{C}, \mathscr{L})-\chi\left(\mathrm{C}, \mathscr{O}_{\mathrm{C}}\right) .
$$

And

(Görtz&Wedhorn's 15.9) In particular, we can speak of the degree of a line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on $C$. We have
$$
\operatorname{deg} \mathscr{L}=\chi\left(\mathscr{O}_C\right)-\chi\left(\mathscr{L}^{-1}\right) .
$$
and $\operatorname{deg} D=\operatorname{deg} \mathscr{O}_C(D)$ for every divisor $D$ on $C$.

Are these two definitions the same? I tried to show it via

18.4.A. EXERCISE. Show that if $0 \rightarrow \mathscr{F} \rightarrow \mathscr{G} \rightarrow \mathscr{H} \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of coherent sheaves on a projective k-scheme X , then $\chi(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{G})=\chi(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{F})+\chi(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{H})$.

But I cannot find suitable exact sequence for it. Also maybe the Riemann Roch theorem help? But I am quite interested in the singular case too and RR seems failed in this situation.

Maybe I get it from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AYV where the def is as Vakil’s but taking $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{E}^\vee$ in the linked ref gives the equation as G&W.

yes, taking $X = C$, $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}$ in the link will give $\chi(C, \mathcal{O}_C) = \deg \mathcal{L} + \chi(C, \mathcal{L}^{-1})$, so G & W's definition follows.

@kobe that looks like an answer to me. Would you care to record it as such below?

Setting $X = C$, $\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{L}^{-1}$ in Stacks, Lemma 33.44.5, we get $$\chi(C, \mathscr{O}_C) = \chi(C, \mathscr{L}\otimes \mathscr{L}^{-1}) = \deg \mathscr{L} + \chi(C, \mathscr{L}^{-1})$$ or $\deg \mathscr{L} = \chi(C, \mathscr{O}_C) - \chi(C,\mathscr{L}^{-1})$, which is Görtz and Wedhorn's definition.
